# Is War actually a game?

Tags: terminology

There's a simple card "game" out there called [War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_%28card_game%29).  You take a deck of cards, shuffle it and divide it into two piles.  Both players reveal their top card, whoever has the higher card wins the round.  This continues until you run out of cards and you see who's won.  (There's a wrinkle for ties that isn't relevant here.)

During a game of War, neither player has any choice at all -- their actions are entirely predetermined by the order of the deck.

**Is this a game?**

Comment: See discussion here: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/are-questions-about-games-that-require-no-decision-making-acceptable

Comment: Depending on why you're asking this question, it might be better suited for http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @GendoIkari, some context of why I'm asking: I work for a company that publishes tabletop games and we're having a brainstorm-type discussion on future products.

Comment: By this logic Candyland is also not a game, even though most people would call it one.

Comment: I think that when you ask "Is War a game?", you are looking at the wrong issue. Presumably, what you really want to know is whether War is relevant to your brainstorm. It shouldn't matter so much what word you use to refer to it as what qualities it has (including marketability) and whether those qualities are what you are looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be: yes is a game because our faq and meta said it? The question is not bad, but I don't know what type of answer are you specting...